# Mismatch between array dtype ('float32') and format specifier('%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,

Tags: python, numpy, caffe

I want to save a numpy array to a file,in which the elements are all decimal like this:

> [[[ 48.83469772  47.3260498   50.89575958 ...,  73.66060638 
>   67.25086212
>       57.77824402]   [ 48.16837311  47.98483658  49.86344528 ...,  75.42465973  67.45271301
>       59.04011536]   [ 37.2819252   38.56423569  41.01593018 ...,  60.42554855  56.19502258
>       50.14974594]   ...,    [ 33.68757629  34.1117363   34.183918   ...,  99.32286835  90.29943085
>       82.34357452]   [ 26.22864342  26.86834335  28.4664669  ...,  78.21855927  75.16976929
>       69.43063354]   [ 25.72758675  27.40409279  27.56349945 ...,  79.87226868  74.75447083
>       70.91829681]]
>
> [[-19.16264725 -21.61523056 -25.82892609 ..., -12.98780441
>   -12.88589764
>       -5.9541235 ]   [-22.31830597 -22.04252052 -29.3843441  ..., -13.48797131 -16.810112
>       -7.06621695]   [-24.21283913 -27.54284286 -26.17948151 ..., -23.72899437 -15.81757355    -12.02238655]   ...,    [ -7.59762573 -10.51124859 -17.69021988 ...,  -9.16242027 -19.5943985    -12.75421238]   [ -8.19426441 -13.31349087 -14.81684589 ..., -23.96293831 -17.367136    -18.59004211]   [ -9.63488102 -13.01188278 -16.63376999 ..., -24.13410759 -21.61151695    -18.9569912 ]]
>
> [[-21.14115715 -22.41012573 -15.25452423 ..., -59.50307083
>   -55.15005875    -63.48766327]   [-18.17512703 -17.58512878 -12.30570889 ..., -51.21564865 -49.47551727    -55.8404274 ]   [ -8.84760571  -9.2598753   -7.2519393  ..., -37.10710144 -39.99137115    -45.80800629]   ...,    [-11.0025959   -7.40627909  -0.29789227 ..., -64.20973206 -56.41481018    -59.39144516]   [ -4.97204161  -2.86881089   2.50408983 ..., -44.36228561 -43.0019989    -46.14816284]   [ -4.39526129  -0.89084005   2.85988808 ..., -36.5013504  -38.57440567    -38.77297974]]
>
> [[ -8.58478737  -3.35468864  -9.80554676 ...,  -1.04906297
>   0.83105278
>       11.70983791]   [ -7.72863674  -8.41098309  -8.16646671 ..., -10.6003046   -1.1207552
>        3.91280365]   [ -4.20178986  -1.7421155   -7.50616026 ...,   0.4124999   -0.48395967
>        7.58291054]   ...,    [-15.14459419 -16.25154686 -16.17931557 ..., -25.90099335 -14.28762531    -10.19545174]   [-13.0495739 
>   -10.67337513 -15.9024334  ...,  -9.96191025 -14.77223778
>       -4.66390228]   [-11.68454742 -13.48856163 -13.53823853 ..., -19.30517197 -14.53974152    -13.15965939]]]

here is my code.`score` is a 4*224*224 numpy array:

> score=net.blobs['upscore1'].data[0] np.savetxt("score1.txt",score)

but I meet the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "infer.py", line 27, in
>   
>       np.savetxt("score1.txt",score, delimiter=',',fmt='%.18e')   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line
>   1219, in savetxt
>       % (str(X.dtype), format)) TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('float32') and format specifier
>   ('%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e')

Comment: Savetxt only works with 2d arrays.  Yours is 3d.  There's no standard handling for showing 3d as simple delimited rows and columns.

Comment: why not use `h5py` and save the data in binary `hdf5` format?

Comment: Or even simpler, as a numpy array with [np.save](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html)?

Comment: I tried np.save but the content is messy code

Comment: Having the same problem -- I want to save it to a text for viewing/reading purposes.